# how to scroll a listview in android using appium?

Tags: android, ruby, selenium, appium

I used the following statement to scroll .

```
  @driver.scroll_to_exact('Text').click
```

I got the following error

`Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError:unexpected response, code=404, content-type="text/plain"That URL did not map to a valid JSONWP resource`

I tried using the following statement

```
     b=find_element(:id,'com.dddd.main:id/calenderListView')
     @driver.execute_script 'mobile: scrollTo', :element => b.ref`
```

I was able to scroll till the end of the list view .But got the following error after scrolling to end of listview

```
  Failure/Error: @driver.execute_script 'mobile: scrollTo', :element => b.ref
 Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError:
   Could not scroll element into view: null
 # ./test.rb:68:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Answer (score 3):

Hope this helps:

**STEP:**

```
Given(/^I scroll down/) do
element = find_element :xpath, "//YOUR_ELEMENT_HERE']"
execute_script 'mobile: scrollTo', :element => element.ref
end
```

---

**FEATURE:**

```
Given I scroll down
```

---

You don't have to use xpath to locate element, if you have id or name it would be better choice